# How to copy values from one df to the original df with a certain condition?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, copy

Currently I am working on clustering problem and I have a problem with copying the values from one dataframe to the original dataframe.

```
    CustomerID | Date |     Time| TotalSum | CohortMonth| CohortIndex
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0   |17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|15.30|2017-11-01|1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|20.34|2017-11-01|1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2   |17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|22.00|2017-11-01|1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
3   |17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|20.34|2017-11-01|1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the dataframe with values (clusters) to copy:

```
CustomerID|Cluster
------------------
12346.0   |     1
------------------
12346.0   |     1
------------------
12346.0   |     1
------------------
```

Please help me with the problem: How to copy values from the second df based on Customer ID criteria to the first dataframe.

I tried the code like this:

```
df.merge(ic,left_on='CustomerID',right_on='Cluster',how='left').drop('CustomerID',1).fillna('')
```

But it doesn't work and I get an error...

Besides it tried a version of such code as:

```
df, ic = [d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in (df, ic)]
ic.join(df[['CustomerID']])
```

But it gets the same error or error like the 'Customer ID' not in df...
Sorry if it's not clear and bad formatted question...It is my first question on stackoverflow. Thank you all.

**UPDATE**

I have tried this

```
df1=df.merge(ic,left_on='CustomerID',right_on='Cluster',how='left')

 if ic['CustomerID'].values != df1['CustomerID_x'].values:
    df1.Cluster=ic.Cluster
 else:
    df1.Cluster='NaN'
```

But I've got different cluster for the same customer.

### CustomerID_x| Date | Time | TotalSum | CohortMonth | CohortIndex | CustomerID_y | Cluster

### 0|17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|15.30 | 2017-11-01 | 1 | NaN | 1.0

### 1|17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|20.34 | 2017-11-01 | 1 | NaN | 0.0

### 2|17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|22.00 | 2017-11-01 | 1 | NaN | 1.0

### 3|17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|20.34 | 2017-11-01 | 1 | NaN | 2.0

### 4|17850.0|2017-11-29||08:26:00|20.34 | 2017-11-01 | 1 | NaN | 1.0

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide the code to initialize the dataframes so that people can copy-paste as a base to work from. Something like `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID':[0, 1, ...` Also, if you could surround your in-line code with backticks `to make it read more like code`, that would be great.

Comment: Here the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/116X3qZQrQClMKgKrjscT0KqjnueFMfJi?usp=sharing) for downloading csv files with data. I have greatly changed the original set, so I give you the files with the transformed data

Comment: I'd tried `df.merge(ic,left_on='CustomerID',right_on='Cluster',how='left').drop('CustomerID',1).fillna('')` and got empty column 'Cluster' in df. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you've written, I *think* you want:

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"CustomerID": [17850.0] * 4, "CohortIndex": [1,1,1,1] })
>>> df1
   CustomerID  CohortIndex
0     17850.0            1
1     17850.0            1
2     17850.0            1
3     17850.0            1

>>> df2
   CustomerID  Cluster
0     12346.0        1
1     17850.0        1
2     12345.0        1

>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, 'left', 'CustomerID')
   CustomerID  CohortIndex  Cluster
0     17850.0            1        1
1     17850.0            1        1
2     17850.0            1        1
3     17850.0            1        1
```

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. I need lookup excel function, if you know how it wirks